# Fancy tree event for render completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

I am using the fancytree for my application. 
https://github.com/mar10/fancytree

I can see the list of events from their plugin. 
http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/global.html#FancytreeEvents

But I could not find an event for the following scenario.

Which is the event that I can use to identify whether the fancy tree completed the rendering job.

Comment: The question is not clear. What is `rendering job`? Please post your code also

Comment: Judging from the docs, it should be the *create* event. The naming is a bit unfortunate, but the description is clear: "Widget **was** created (called only once, even if re-initialized)."

Comment: @TanDuong, don't you understand? The question is, when we do an action with the list of data with Fancytree, It will populate the elements in the DOM. I wanted to know the event that to identify when Fancytree completed it's rendering job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that ‘init’ is probably the event that you are looking for.
Note however that fancytree only renders visible nodes, i.e. when the parent is expanded.

Comment: `init` is fired when the tree is first fully visible in the DOM. Great!
BUT: If children are loaded via lazyload, it will not be fired again.